# AesCryptoServiceProvider "The input data is not a complete block"

Tags: c#

I wrote two programs in C#. One does the encryption, and the other one does the decryption. The decryption program throws exception of "The input data is not a complete block" with data from the encryption program. However the decryption program works fine with the encrypted data from a Unix encryption program, using PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1().

Encrypted data is base 64 encoded, and saved in a text file. The first 8 bytes is a salt, the next 16 bytes is an IV, and the rest is the application text.

I would appreciate very much if anyone could help.

```
    public static string DecryptText(string cipherData)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_passwd))
            return null;

        var decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherData);

        // First 8 bytes contain the salt used for key derivation. Use the password from the passwd.dat
        // file and the salt to derive the key used to encode the credential.
        //
        var salt = new byte[8];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(decodedBytes, 0, salt, 0, 8);
        var derivedBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(_passwd, salt, 1000);
        var key = derivedBytes.GetBytes(32);

        // Next 16 bytes contain the initialization vector used to encrypt
        //
        var ivBytes = new byte[16];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(decodedBytes, 8, ivBytes, 0, ivBytes.Length);

        // Remaining bytes contain the credential cipher text
        //
        var cipherBytes = new byte[decodedBytes.Length - 8 - 16];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(decodedBytes, 8 + 16, cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);

        string decryptedData = null;
        try
        {
            using (var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                aes.Key = key;
                aes.IV = ivBytes;

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }

                    decryptedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("Caught exception while decryption: {0}: ", ex.Message);
        }

        return decryptedData;
    }

    public static string EncryptText(string plainData)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_passwd))
            return null;

        var rfc2898db = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(_passwd, 8, 1000);
        byte[] salt = new byte[8];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(rfc2898db.Salt, 0, salt, 0, 8);
        byte[] key = new byte[32];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(rfc2898db.GetBytes(32), 0, key, 0, 32);

        string cipherData;

        try
        {
            var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider
            {
                Key = key,
                KeySize = 256,
                BlockSize = 128,
                Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
                Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
            };
            aes.GenerateIV();

            byte[] encrypted;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    ms.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length);
                    ms.Write(salt, 0, 8);
                    cs.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainData), 0, plainData.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }

                encrypted = ms.ToArray();
            }

            byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[SaltLength + IvLength + encrypted.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, encryptedBytes, 0, SaltLength);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(aes.IV, 0, encryptedBytes, SaltLength, IvLength);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(encrypted, 0, encryptedBytes, SaltLength + IvLength, encrypted.Length);

            cipherData = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("Caught exception while encryption: {0}", ex.Message);
            return null;
        }

        return cipherData;
    }
```

Comment: You don't seem to be specifying any padding for the decryptor AesCryptoServiceProvider, but you do specify it for the one on the encryptor.

Comment: Yes. If I take out "Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7" from encryption, the same exception is thrown in decryption.

Comment: What's the Linux program look like?